# Generating Swagger from Request/Response

Tags: rest, swagger

I need to generate a swagger document using the request response model. 
I have heard that there are ways of generating the same but i have never used it.

Comment: Which framework are you using?

Comment: i am asking is there any framework available either in java using maven or in node side.

Comment: I am able to use node-red-node-swagger which allow us with this capability. But the Issue now i am facing is it does not allow me to add nested objects inside the response body